# Alamofire Basic and Oauth2

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

I have been using Alamofire and it works fine for basic auth #1

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, ENDPOINT_URL).authenticate(user:_username, password: _password).responseJSON { response in }
```

and for OAuth2 #2

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(getLoginToken()!)"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, ENDPOINT_URL2, parameters: para, headers: headers,encoding: .JSON ).responseJSON {  response in }
```

Now i am changing some of the API  authentication to OAuth2, it will be a mixture of both Basic and OAuth. The problem comes at #3

1. I make Basic Auth Request first, authentication pass
2. I make OAuth2 Request first, authentication pass
3. I make Basic Auth Request and OAuth2 Request, authentication pass for Basic Auth and fail for OAuth2.

After debugging, i realise that it is still sending the Basic Auth Request headers and the newly added headers is not reflected and updated to Alamofire.

I hava a Singleton APIClient class that calls `Alamofire.request()`. When i examine the Alamofire class, it turns out that the `Manager` is also a singleton class. I am guessing it could be due to the above singletons.

Any advice on how to send to pass the headers correctly? Or how to do Basic Auth & OAuth2 one after another?

> Alamofire: v3.1.2
>
> XCode: 7.2.1
>
> IOS: 9

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faced similar problems. I use [SwiftyHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) for the basic OAuth and `Alamofire` for OAuth2.

Though not a perfect solution, but its working fine.